# Problem sizing the image with \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, scaling

This question is very similar to [Image from \includegraphics showing in wrong image size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21627/image-from-includegraphics-showing-in-wrong-image-size), but not quite the same.

The size of the image that appears in my manuscript depends entirely on the dpi setting I give it in IrfanView. It doesn't matter which `width` or `scale` settings I use - these settings only determine the horizontal and vertical offset of my image. Now I have tried including the same image in both .png and .pdf format, always the same result.

However, I have used .eps figures a lot, and there it very easy to change the size with a simple `width`. Is it somehow possible to do the same with figures that are not .eps? I will be dealing with a lot of figures in the next few months and would prefer controlling the image size directly from within LaTeX, instead of having to go through another program.

I am using pdflatex with the `graphicx` package and define my figure as such:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{MyFigure.png}
  \caption{My Caption}
  \label{fig::myFig}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: As far as I know you have to set all images to the same dpi before you use them in TeX. See [DPI for imported bitmaps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153489). And [Uncertain about dpi in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108519) and comments. Or in general the tag [tag:resolution].

Comment: The package `graphics` knows the following driver options: `dvips`, `xdvi`, `dvipdf`, `dvipdfm`, `dvipdfmx`, `xetex`, `pdftex`, `dviwindo`, `emtex`, `dviwin`, `oztex`, `textures`, `pctexps`, `pctexwin`, `pctexhp`, `pctex32`, `truetex`, `tcidvi`, `vtex`. Each DVI driver or TeX engine has different capabilities regarding images. Therefore it is quite important to know, which driver you are using. Also add a MWE to clarify, what you are doing. I know about keys `width` and `scale` for `\includegraphics` of package `graphicx`. But `\width` and `\scale` settings could mean something different.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and my excuses for not being very clear. I have found and posted the solution, and have added details to the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few hours of trial and error it turns out that a package setting for a different package was causing the problem in graphicx. I was using a template given to me by someone else which had:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvips]{color}
```

defined. Alas, the `dvips` option was causing the problem. Removing it I am now able to include a .png with `\includegraphics` and set the size with the the `width` option.

Comment: Never set options such as `dvips` or `pdftex` to `color`, `xcolor` or `graphicx`; this limits portability and those packages are able to figure out the current typesetting engine by themselves.